# How to run multiple ajax request simultaneously

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have an AJAX request which fires off a Laravel event. Straight after calling the first AJAX, I have another AJAX which will be called immediately.

However, my issue is that the 2nd AJAX doesn't get called until the first one return completes. Is there a way of running my 2nd AJAX before the 1st one completes?

1st AJAX is adding records into DB however 2nd AJAX is used to check the performance/printing out logs as to what's happening.

If code is required, please let me know. I thought there was no need for the code.

An example of how my ajax looks like

```
        $.ajax({
            url: '{{route('job-updates')}}',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': "{!! csrf_token() !!}"
            },
            data: {},
            async : 'false',
        }).always(function (response) {
            console.log(response);

            if (response.message === 'no_job') {
                ajaxRunning = false;
            }

            else if (ajaxRunning) {
                //After 5 seconds fire the update
                setTimeout(function () {
                    getJobUpdates()
                }, 5000);
            }
        });
```

Comment: AJAX is async by default.

Comment: Is there any other way of doing???

Comment: Can I do a normal form post on first and then do ajax to check for progress??

Comment: _However, my issue is that the 2nd AJAX doesn't get called until the first one return completes_ I don't believe that. Have you explicitly set `async` to `false`?

Comment: @vivek_23 i just updated the question to show an example of ajax request I am doing

Comment: Remove the async: false thing. You are making it synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

You can use promises for this kind of actions

```js
function functionOne() {
    return $.ajax({})    
}

function functionTwo() {
    return $.ajax({})    
}

Promise.all([
    functionOne(),
    functionTwo(),
]).then(function() {
    
});
```